# How to rotate a camera around a LookAt point with a varying distance?

Tags: 3d

I have a formula that gives me what i roughly want. But what i precisely want is the ability to do this WITH distance. let me explain.

Below is the formula which makes the Camera rotate around a Point (LookAt point).

```
this.Position.X = this.LookAt.X + Math.sin(angle);
this.Position.Z = this.LookAt.Z + Math.cos(angle);
```

The angle (above) is being updated by 0.15 (+ or -) based on whether im pressing Left or Right keys.
This gives the effect that my camera is rotating around a point which is right in front of the camera.

**What i want is this:**
To be able to rotate the camera around a lookat point (like the current behavior), but allow the camera to "zoom in" or "zoom out" based on the distance to the lookat point.

I tried something like the following, but it did not give the desired effect:

```
this.Position.X = this.LookAt.X + Math.sin(angle);
this.Position.Z = this.LookAt.Z + Math.cos(angle);
this.Position.X *= distance;
this.Position.Z *= distance;
```

Comment: This question has nothing to do with WebGL, OpenGL, OpenGLES nor Perspective Cameras. The only code you're showing is related to some library you haven't named

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I read your description, I think this will give you what you want:

```
this.Position.X = this.LookAt.X + distance * Math.sin(angle);
this.Position.Z = this.LookAt.Z + distance * Math.cos(angle);
```

With the way you had it, you would multiply the `LookAt` point by `distance` as well, which means that it will move as you zoom. If you want to keep looking at the same point, but only move closer/farther, you only need to multiply the position relative to the `LookAt` point.